# jQuery add crescent classes to elements inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of article elements added dynamically inside a section. I need each article to have a crescent class (fp_1, fp_2, fp_3, ...).
How can I pull it of with jquery?

```
<section id="featured_posts">
  <article class="fp_1"></article>
  <article class="fp_2"></article>
  <article class="fp_3"></article>
</section>

$('#featured_posts article').addClass('fp_*');
```

It's the way to make the class crescent that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function as `addClass` param, like this:

```
$('#featured_posts article').addClass(function(index) {
  return 'fp_' + (index + 1);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fnn8wgsn/). The function is called for each element in the set, it receives the 0-based index of that element - hence adding 1 is required (as your indexing is apparently 1-based).

If there's already `fp` class on those elements, just remove it with `removeClass`:

```
$('#featured_posts article').removeClass('fp').addClass(...);
```

Comment: somehow it doesn't work, each article uses wordpress post_class this way '<article <?php post_class('featuredpost'); ?>>' could jquery .addClass conflict with this in any way?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean here. In particular, why can't you just use `get_post_class` instead and assign an incrementing class counter on the server-side? Anyway, if you use `post_class`, you should probably remove `'featuredpost'` class from those elements.

Comment: that could be an option, how can I do it only for posts inside #featured_posts?

Comment: That depends on how the posts are created. Show your server-side code (better in a separate question, as this one is answered, as you can see from a demo).